# Show the quotient groups of two nonzero rational numbers are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let x, y be rational numbers. Show Q/$\langle x \rangle$ is isomorphic to Q/$\langle y \rangle$.

I know to show isomorphic you need to show that there is a bijection and f(uv) = f(u)*f(v), but I can't think of such a bijection

Comment: When you say $\{x\}$ are you talking about the subgroup generated by $x$?

Comment: @wgrenard yes.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Try multiplication by $\frac{x}{y}$ as a map $\mathbb Q/\langle y\rangle \to \mathbb Q/\langle x\rangle$.  You'll need to show that this gives you a well defined map, that this map is a homomorphism, and that this homomorphism is bijective.

Comment: thanks.  I'm a little confused though trying to show f(uv) = f(u)f(v).  The map I defined is f(a) = ax/y.  Then f(ab) = abx/y $\neq$ ax/y * bx/y.  Did I define the map wrong?

Comment: The group operation is addition.